# Setting default browser when debugging playwright tests

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I am trying to figure out how to change the default browser when debugging playwright tests using VSCODE.  Currently, in VSCODE when I run or debug it defaults to chrome.  I want to change that to use webkit and cannot seem to find where that setting is.

Thank you in advance for your help
Christine

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set the default project (don't forget to also set it for the debug config)

[image]